# how to create and run cronjob which delete database files

Tags: c#, asp.net, cron

I have made a application in c# with a RavenDB.

Now i need some assistant at creating a cronjob script which runs like 3 time's a day to delete files in my database older than 15 days.

Answer (score 0):

An easy couple of steps:

- Write a *.bat script to do your logic
- use Task Scheduler to run the script according to the desired schedule

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) in the past and that contains a CronTrigger. Very flexible and well documented.

Answer (score 0):

if its an app in asp.net you can call the function in App_Start function of global.aspx page using timer controls which repeat after a certain amount of time.

you can refer to this Url for more details

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc